# Shopify Rest API to create a draft order

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api-node

I'm creating a draft order using this.

```
{
     "draft_order": {
       "line_items": [
         {
            "custom": false,
            "title": "Custom Product",
            "product_id" : 4008421883976,
            "price" : "1000.00",
              "properties": [
                {
                  "name": "custom engraving",
                  "value": "Happy Birthday Mom!"
                }
              ],
            "quantity": 5
         }
       ],
       "customer": {       
         "id": 1000
       },
       "email": "test@test.com"
     }
   }
```

But I want to show product image and product link in draft order.

How can I do this?

If line_item is custom one then it is showing Custom Title and no image and no option.

I can't use variant_id because price is very different based on product options.

So I need to use custom one but want to add product url and image in draft order.

How can I do this?

Comment: Are you able to create draft order usingin `product_id` instead of `variant_id` ?

Comment: you have to pass variant ID in order to show links to product/variant in the order detail page. if this is just for price differentiation you can explicitly pass price of this variant which might be different than original amount. this will be accepted by Shopify. and price of this order item will be taken from your request object.